# Single M3U8 playlist file with different bitrate support

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I need to share a m3u8 playlist with support for different bitrate and resolution.

The master playlist consist of different bitrate playlist.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=256000
bbb_30sec_256.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=768000
bbb_30sec_768.m3u8
```

Instead is it possible to get a single playlist with all bitrates files included.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:16
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=256000,RESOLUTION=480x270
#EXTINF:15.833333,
bbb_30sec_256_00000.ts
#EXTINF:14.250000,
bbb_30sec_256_00001.ts
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=768000,RESOLUTION=640x360 
#EXTINF:15.833333,
bbb_30sec_768_00000.ts
#EXTINF:14.250000,
bbb_30sec_768_00001.ts
```

Apple [HLS document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-BASIC_VARIANT_PLAYLIST) doesn't gave any scope for that. I was curious to know is this can be achieved in any other possible way?

Comment: No. ___________

Comment: You can achieve this only by writing your own player, but then it won't be called HLS player.

Comment: Ok Got it. Only custom HLS player can do this.